# Laravel Mailtrap Localhost - Error sending mail

Tags: laravel, email

I would like to send a emai to a `gmail` address using `Laravel 5.4` and `Mailtrap` while working on my `localhost:8888`.

I've got this error `Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required`

I tried

- Using different port
- `php artisan config:clear`

What is wrong ?

## .env

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
    MAIL_PORT=465
    MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxx
    MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxx
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=example@example.com
    MAIL_FROM_NAME=Leo
```

## config/mail.php

```
 'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
  'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailtrap.io'),
  'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
  ],
  'username' => env('xxxxx'),
  'password' => env('xxxxx'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to change

```
'username' => env('xxxxx'),
'password' => env('xxxxx'),
```

to

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

Comment: I wanted to find someone else with this problem, because yesterday it took me like 5 hours to figure this out. Nice catch, wish I had this yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

```
The below code (in .env file) solved my problem in sending verification 
email - Laravel 5.7. No need to change in config/mail.php

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.somedomain.org
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=someone@somedomain.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_pwd
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=someone@somedomain.org
MAIL_FROM_NAME=SenderName
```